# Take the first item of a list in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am following a tutorial to make API Calls using Swift but I need to take only the first item of the array retrieved. So, my question is: "What is the best way to pick the first element of an Array/Dictionary of JSON Objects?".

I am trying several ways but they show me no light at the end of the tunnel.

Here's the example code.

PokemonAPIList.swift

```
import Foundation

struct PokemonAPIList: Decodable {
    var results: [PokemonListEntry]
}

struct PokemonListEntry: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var url: String
}
```

PokemonNetworkManager.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class PokemonNetworkManager: ObservableObject {
  
   @Published var results = [PokemonListEntry]()
     
   init() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151") else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            let pokemonList = try! JSONDecoder().decode(PokemonAPIList.self, from: data)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.results = pokemonList.results
            }
        }.resume()
   }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
    
struct ContentView: View {
   @ObservedObject var networkingManager = PokemonNetworkManager()

var body: some View {
    let bulbasaur = networkingManager.results.first
    
    Text(bulbasaur!.name) //Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
        .bold()
}

/*THIS CODE BELOW WORKS
List(networkingManager.results, id:\.name) { pokemon in
            Text(pokemon.name)
        }
*/

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: To get help with your code on Stack Overflow, you'll need to actually share the code itself: see [mre]. You've said you get errors but you haven't said what they are, and we can't read your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you exactly want but if you need to return the first element of an array of objects you can do it:

```
array.first()
```

if not please provide you full code to be able to help you

Comment: It returns me the following error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: See the edited code

Comment: So either the array is nil, or its first element.

Comment: But if I put the array in the List, the code works and shows me all the 151 Pokemons

Comment: I can't take the first element

Comment: Try `if let first = array.first { ... }`.

Comment: I put the working code (with the List) up in the post so you can see what is working and what is not working

Comment: I'm gonna check it

Comment: koen, the code you provided works. Can you explain why yours works and mine doesn't?

Comment: It works because you check if the first element has value or not "existing or not" and if it's existing it will print it, if not it won't crash

Comment: @K0sm: Glad it works. I highly recommend you read up on using and unwrapping optionals in Swift.